# How can i bring a variable through a button

Tags: html, svelte

I am making a simple shopping website and i wanted to make a loop that created a display for all the items.

```
<script>
    function Test(A) {
        alert(A)
    }
</script>

<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <button on:click = {Test("Hello")}>Test button</button>
</body>
```

Currently i am running this function and i am getting the alert when loading the website and then the button doesn't do anything. How do i fix this?

Comment: `<button on:click={Test("Hello")}>Test button</button>` it works just remove the space near "="

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this:

```
<button on:click={() => Test("Hello")}>Test button</button>
```

By doing `on:click={Test("Hello")}`, you are saying "call `Test` when the page loads and add the return value as a click handler on the button." This is why the function is only called once. Instead, you want to pass a reference to a function -- this way, the function is called on each click.